# RecycleView gets corrupted after record delete

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have [Android RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView) showing some locations via [RecyclerView.Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) and [ArrayList](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/ArrayList) of [Pair](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/util/Pair) of [Boolean](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Boolean) and `PlantRecord`:

```
package com.mikroelektronika.guestnotificationsystem.Database;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class PlantRecord implements Serializable
{
    private static final String TAG=PlantRecord.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String TABLE_ID="plants";

    public static final String FIELD_ID="id";
    public static final String FIELD_NAME="name";
    public static final String FIELD_PHOTO_URL="photo_url";
    public static final String FIELD_STREET="street";
    public static final String FIELD_STREET_NR="street_nr";
    public static final String FIELD_ZIPCODE="zip_code";
    public static final String FIELD_CITY="city";
    public static final String FIELD_COUNTRY="country";

    public static final String INVALID_FIELD_ID_VALUE="";
    public static final String INVALID_FIELD_NAME_VALUE="";
    public static final String INVALID_FIELD_PHOTO_URL_VALUE="";
    public static final String INVALID_FIELD_STREET_VALUE="";
    public static final String INVALID_FIELD_STREET_NR_VALUE="";
    public static final String INVALID_FIELD_ZIPCODE_VALUE="";
    public static final String INVALID_FIELD_CITY_VALUE="";
    public static final String INVALID_FIELD_COUNTRY_VALUE="";

    public String id;
    public String name;
    public String photo_url;
    public String street;
    public String street_nr;
    public String zip_code;
    public String city;
    public String country;

    public PlantRecord()
    {
        this.id=INVALID_FIELD_ID_VALUE;
        this.name=INVALID_FIELD_NAME_VALUE;
        this.photo_url=INVALID_FIELD_PHOTO_URL_VALUE;
        this.street=INVALID_FIELD_STREET_VALUE;
        this.street_nr=INVALID_FIELD_STREET_NR_VALUE;
        this.zip_code=INVALID_FIELD_ZIPCODE_VALUE;
        this.city=INVALID_FIELD_CITY_VALUE;
        this.country=INVALID_FIELD_COUNTRY_VALUE;
    }

    public PlantRecord(final String id,
        final String name,
        final String photo_url,
        final String street,
        final String street_nr,
        final String zip_code,
        final String city,
        final String country)
    {
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.photo_url=photo_url;
        this.street=street;
        this.street_nr=street_nr;
        this.zip_code=zip_code;
        this.city=city;
        this.country=country;
    }

    public static Comparator<PlantRecord> plantRecordComparatorByPlantNameAscending=Comparator.comparing(firstPlantRecord->
                                                                                                             firstPlantRecord.name);

    public static Comparator<PlantRecord> plantRecordComparatorByPlantNameDescending=(firstPlantRecord, secondPlantRecord)->secondPlantRecord.name
        .compareTo(firstPlantRecord.name);

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "id:"+
               this.id+
               " "+
               "name:"+
               this.name+
               " "+
               "photo_url:"+
               this.photo_url+
               " "+
               "street:"+
               this.street+
               " "+
               "street_nr:"+
               this.street_nr+
               " "+
               "zip_code:"+
               this.zip_code+
               " "+
               "city:"+
               this.city+
               " "+
               "country:"+
               this.country;
    }
}
```

as datasource:

```
package com.mikroelektronika.guestnotificationsystem.PlantsSelector;

import android.util.Pair;

import com.mikroelektronika.guestnotificationsystem.Database.PlantRecord;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * @brief Data source data structure
 * @param first - Boolean for selected record (multiselection) true - selected false - unselected
 * @param second - Plant record
 */
public class PlantsDataSource extends ArrayList<Pair<Boolean, PlantRecord>>
{
}
```

Datasource if populated correctly at startup and `RecyclerView` is also filled and shown correctly from [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/):
[image: Data from Google Firebase shown RecyclerView]
Now, if needed, item is selected and then deleted via [ImageButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton) with following deletion process code:

```
this.btnDeletePlant.setOnClickListener(v -> {

    if (selectedPlantsItems.size() > 0) {

        for (Pair<Integer, PlantRecord> selectedPlantItem : selectedPlantsItems) {
            DatabaseReference removingPlantRecordRef =
                    FirebaseDatabase
                            .getInstance()
                            .getReference()
                            .child(PlantRecord.TABLE_ID)
                            .child(CurrentLoggedUser.getUserId())
                            .child(selectedPlantItem.second.id);

            Log.i(TAG, "selectedPlantItem.second.id:" + selectedPlantItem.second.id);

            removingPlantRecordRef.removeValue()

                    .addOnCanceledListener(() -> Log.i(TAG, "Remove canceled."))

                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Remove completed.");
                        }
                    })

                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.e(TAG, "Remove failed with error:" + e))

                    .addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Remove successfull, selected plant item index:" + selectedPlantItem.first);
                        plantsSelectionFragmentAdapter.removeItem(selectedPlantItem.first);
                    });
        }
    }
    
});
```

We can also see in the [Android Studio Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat) item is deleted without errors:

```
2023-04-10 13:04:02.339 16640-16640 PlantSelectionFragment  com.mikroelektronika                 I  selectedPlantItem.second.id:-NSef13zeWQL1Sim-iPo
2023-04-10 13:04:02.404 16640-16640 PlantSelectionFragment  com.mikroelektronika                 I  Remove completed.
2023-04-10 13:04:02.404 16640-16640 PlantSelectionFragment  com.mikroelektronika                 I  Remove successfull, selected plant item
```

[image: Android Studio Logccat]

I've checked 50 or more times the right item is removed from `Firebase` and indeed it is. However, `RecyclerView` gets corrupted as seen in tthe following screen record (converted to [animated gif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF#Animated_GIF)):
[image: Item removal recyclerview coruption]
Why is this happening, I have no idea how to fix this?

**ADDENDUM 1**

@dominicoder here is `removeItem(final int itemIndex)` code:

```
public void removeItem(final int itemIndex)
{
    this.plantsDataSource
        .remove(itemIndex);

    notifyItemRemoved(itemIndex);
    this.selectedItemsCounter
        .decrease();
}
```

It removes item from data source and notifies adapter about removal at the end it also decreases selected items counter. However, I've tested item removal **with** and **without** this method, result is same. Error must be somewhere in the item removal from database ...

**ADDENDUM 2**

If I disable `Firebase` saving code and just call `removeItem` in *delete item button onClickListener*, item is correctly removed from `RecyclerView`, will check `removingPlantRecordRef` ...

Comment: Your code formatting is unreadable, please fix it. Are you notifying the adapter of the removal?

Comment: What does `plantsSelectionFragmentAdapter.removeItem(selectedPlantItem.first)` do?

Comment: @m0skit0 I have rewritten the question from sratch ... Code should be readable now ...
@dominicoder I've updated the question, like I've written, `removeItem` removes item from datasource, notifies adapter and decreases selected items counter - all of this **AFTER** successful removal from `Firebase` ...

Comment: Instead of notifyItemRemoved, call directly notifyDataSetChanged(), this method will refresh the whole RecyclerView, but it will flick instead of animation.

When using the notifyItemRemoved you need DiffUtils for the RecyclerView adapter to know which item has been removed. Check more details on the following link:

https://copyprogramming.com/howto/efficiently-remove-item-from-android-recyclerview-adapter-key-points-and-best-practices

An easy fix is the notifyDataSetChanged method call instead, but it comes with the price of flickering.

Comment: @mmmatey I get same result.

Comment: @KernelPanic if you got the same results it means that the data should be checked. Try to log the "dataSource" to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

> *Disclaimer*
>
> This is a directive answer rather than a direct answer to the question. So that it could give some clue to solve the OP Question.

---

So, you have a loop that iterates over a list of `PlantRecord` items, then 4 listeners are registered for each (Cancellation, Success, Failure, and Completion), So, if you have a list of 100 items; 400 listeners are registered overall. This is fairly big number and can be error-prone.

Instead of that you can register a single `ChildEventListener` to the parent node of those 100 children/items.

i.e., instead of using this reference:

```
DatabaseReference removingPlantRecordRef =
        FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child(PlantRecord.TABLE_ID)
                .child(CurrentLoggedUser.getUserId())
                .child(selectedPlantItem.second.id);
```

You'd use the parent:

```
DatabaseReference parentRef =
        FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child(PlantRecord.TABLE_ID)
                .child(CurrentLoggedUser.getUserId());
```

And register the `ChildEventListener`, and filter the list from the `DataSnapshot` callback parameter; and eventually notify the `RecyclerView` adapter.

Something like:

```
ChildEventListener listener = new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String secondId = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); 
        
        // Now you've "selectedPlantItem.second.id" from Firebase, use it to 
        // filter the "selectedPlantsItems" to get the selectedPlantItem, 
        // then get "selectedPlantItem.first"
        
        for (Pair<Integer, PlantRecord> selectedPlantItem : selectedPlantsItems) {
            if (secondId == selectedPlantItem.second.id) {
                plantsSelectionFragmentAdapter.removeItem(selectedPlantItem.first);
            }
        }

    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {}

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {}

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    
};

parentRef.addChildEventListener(listener);
```